# A question about a passage of the monotone convergence theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**Theorem.** Given a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative extended real-valued $\mathcal{A}-$measurable functions on $X$ such that $$(i)\; f_n\le f_{n+1}\quad\text{on}\; X\; \text{for all}\; n\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$(ii)\; f_n\to f\quad\text{pointwise in}\; X$$  then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n\;d\mu =\int_X f\;d\mu$$

*Proof.* We fix $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$ and a measurable nonnegative simple function $s$, such that $0\le s\le f$ on $X$. We consider the sequence $\{E_n\}$ of subsets of $X$ by $$E_n=\{x\in X\; |\; (1-\varepsilon)s(x)\le f_n(x)\}\quad (n\in\mathbb{N}).$$

I must prove that
\begin{align}
1.\;&\text{The sets $\{E_n\}$ cannot all be empty.}\\
2.\;& X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n
\end{align}

$1.$ We suppose by absurd that $E_n=\emptyset$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then we have $$(1-\varepsilon)s(x)>f_n(x)\;\forall x\in X, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\implies (1-\varepsilon)s(x)\ge \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\;\forall x\in X\implies (1-\varepsilon)s(x)\ge f(x)\;\forall x\in X,$$ but this is a contradiction, since we have that $f(x)\ge s(x)> (1-\varepsilon)s(x)$, that is $f(x)>(1-\varepsilon)s(x)$.

$2.$ We prove that $X\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. Let $x\in X$.

*First case: $f(x)=0$*

Since $0\le s(x)\le f(x)$ results that $s(x)=0$. Furthermore, since $0\le f_n\le f$, we have that $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. then, $f_n(x)=0=(1-\varepsilon)s(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and therefore $x\in E_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

*Second case: $0<f(x)<\infty$*

Exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(x)>(1-\varepsilon)f(x)$ for all $n>n_0$ (In this case I used the definition of limit taking as epsilon $\varepsilon f(x)$), then $$f_n(x)>(1-\varepsilon)f(x)\ge (1-\varepsilon)s(x)$$ for all $n> n_0$ and therefore $x\in E_n$ for all $n> n_0$.

*Third case: $f(x)=\infty$*

Exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(x)>s(x)$ for all $n>n_0$ (we remember that $s(x)\in\mathbb{R}$) and then, in particular, $f_n(x)>(1-\varepsilon)s(x)$ and this implies that $x\in E_n$ for all $n>n_0$.

Are the proofs correct? Thanks!

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this a bit. The union of empty sets is necessarily the empty set, so $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ implies that the $E_n$ are not all empty. The equality of $X$ with the union of the $E_n$ follows readily from the definition of the $E_n$ and from $f=\sup_n f_n$.

Comment: @Math1000Could you please explain this statement to me in detail? "The equality of $X$ with the union of the $E_n$ follows readily from the definition of the $E_n$ and from $f=\sup_n f_n$"

Comment: Since $0\leqslant s\leqslant f$ and $0<\varepsilon<1$, clearly $(1-\varepsilon)s<f$.  As $f=\sup_n f_n$, there exists $N$ such that $(1-\varepsilon) s \leqslant f_N(x)$ for all $x\in X$, hence $X=E_N$ (and $E_N=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ as $E_n\subset E_{n+1}$ for all $n$).